# Magento2 : When Custom Price applied Product price is not displayed proper with tax on Cart

Tags: magento2.3.0, tax-calculation, custom-prices

Steps to reproduce:

```
1.Please configure tax settings and tax rules as seen in screenshots.

2.Now login in storefront using Demo Customer Access provided by Magento 
  (roni_cost@example.com).

3.Please integrate the below code to apply custom price.
```

**Observer** :

```
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class BindPriceToCart implements ObserverInterface
{

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{   
        $price = 100;
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        return $this;
}    

}
```

**Event** :
checkout_cart_product_add_after

**Configurations that needs to be set** :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Expected Result** :
[image]

**Actual Result** :
[image]

Comment: did you try using another event? Or maybe a plugin. You could try the event `sales_quote_item_set_product`. I'm not saying it will work. I just wondering if using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is not too late in the process to change the price.

Comment: @Marius: I have tried "sales_quote_item_set_product" event but still facing the problem.

Comment: If the custom_price and original_custom_price is set as NULL, once the product is added in cart, then calculation is seen fine on cart. May be magento team should empty the custom_price once the product is added in cart but not sure if it might have impact in other areas or not..